# Contour Integral Question (confusing function)

Tags: complex-analysis

So my function is $f(z) = \sqrt(r)e^{i\theta/2}$.

I want to find its contour integral over the upper half-disk of $z = e^{i\theta}$, where $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$.

I know that:

$\int f(z) dz$ = $\int_a^b f(z(t)) * z'(t) dt$

But in the above problem, the function I want to find the contour integral of isn't in terms of z, it's $f(z) = \sqrt(r)e^{i\theta/2}$

I know this is a branch of $z^{1/2}$ but not sure where to go from here...

Feel like I'm pretty close but missing something

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=z^{1/2}$, with $f(1)=1$, is analytic in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus \{ti: t\in (-\infty,0]\}$, and 
$$
f(z)=\Big(\frac{2}{3}z^{3/2}\Big)'.
$$
So, for $\gamma: [0,\pi]\to\mathbb C$, with $\gamma(t)=\mathrm{e}^{it}$, and $g(z)=\frac{2}{3}z^{3/2}$,
$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=g\big(\gamma(\pi)\big)-g\big(\gamma(0)\big)=\frac{2}{3}\big(\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i}-1\big)=-\frac{4}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This branch of $z^{1/2}$ is analytic on the upper half plane.  What is its antiderivative?  You should have a theorem relating contour integrals to antiderivatives...

Comment: $2/3z^{3/2}$...but this doesn't help me with the parametrization bit, does it?

Comment: The parametrization doesn't matter, just the values of the antiderivative at the endpoints.